# Connecting to Windows 7 from Fedora is slow

Tags: windows-7, windows, fedora, rdesktop

I am using the rdesktop command to connect from a Fedora 14 system to a Windows 7 Professional machine remotely but I get a very slow reponse when I try and connect to it. The command that I used to connect is:

```
rdesktop -4 -C -x -b : -g 100% 192.168.1.100.
```

I have tried using the rdesktop command to connect to the console port as well but the result is the same.

I have even tried using the Terminal Server client application but get the same result.

Is there any tweaking that needs to be done to overcome this issue either on Fedora or Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-z -a 8`.

See if that helps.

Comment: It did help to speed up a bit but the graphical display was bad. The complete command that I used: rdesktop -s -C -D -z -a 8 x:b -g 100% 192.168.1.100. When I used the same command to connect to a windows xp machine it worked brilliant but my problem is connecting to a windows 7 machine which is still slow.